# Is there alternative menu control for VB6?

Tags: vb6

I don't like VB6 menu since it does not provide information about parent or child items. I would like to know if there are activeX menu controls which can be used in VB6 with more features?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [these](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Controls/Toolbar/vbAccelerator_ToolBar_and_CoolMenu_Control/article.asp) out. They are free and may fit your needs.

Beyond free the [Codejock command bars](http://www.codejock.com/products/commandbars/default.asp?platform=com) are very nice.

Comment: Thank you renick. VBAccelarator controls are really nice, but I have to struggle to register the dependencies. Sadly, in this case, I could not run the sample due to missing references. I downloaded the dependency, added a reference, but does not work.

Apart from VBAccelerator, do you know some other ActiveX menu controls designed for VB6?

Comment: +1 for the Codejock comment - although these are not free, you pay for what you get!